Using output[[xxx]] to assign renders dynamically in shiny writes the last processed value to all outputs
I feel like I'm missing something stupidly simple, but I'm stumped.
I have a Shiny app that dynamically generates three table output objects - this part works fine.
However, if I try to populate the tables using output[[x]] <- renderTable(...), it seems to be overwriting each instance with whatever the last-processed version is.
The underlying data frames are correct, however.
So this code generates something like this (three identical tables).

Whereas the correct values appear in the console (i.e., each table is unique).
Note that the third and final table is what appears above.

library(shiny)

chars <- c("A", "B", "C")

tab_ui <- lapply(1:length(chars), function (x) {
  tableOutput(outputId = paste0("table_", x))
})
 
# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  tab_ui
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

   mtcars_react <- reactive({mtcars})
   
   observeEvent(mtcars_react(), {
     x <- mtcars_react()
     for (i in 1:length(chars)) {
       tmp_df <- mtcars_react()[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 3), ]
       print(tmp_df)
       output[[paste0("table_", i)]] <- renderTable(tmp_df)
     }
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


